# Customize Activity page in Redmine 3.2.x

Tags: redmine

We have Redmine 3.2.1 with connected SVN Repository.
On Activity page we see SVN commits like this: 
"Revision XXX (our_svn): #xxx - Change in bla-bla-bla"
Is there any way to add branch and files affected by commit to this message? So it will look like this:
"Revision XXX in branch: Release 5 (our_svn): #xxx - Change in bla-bla-bla
Files affected: index.php, login.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify Redmine default functionality, you have 3 choice

1. Check if someone has already created plugin wich fits your needs on redmine.org and github
2. (preffered) Create your own plugin and upload to github so others can use it as well
3. (not recommended) Modify Redmine's core files, if you do this you will most likely loose compatibility with future versions

In your case I guess it would have to be a mix of 1 and 2, I would take this plugin https://github.com/efigence/redmine_show_assigned_to_activity and modify it's journal_patch.rb to include staff that you need.